# How do you call a Rails helper in a HAML template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Right now I have some filler code in a mockup such as the following:

```
%img{:alt => "image description", :src => "img/img-11.jpg"}
```

Ideally though, I need to reference `img-11.jpg` from the asset pipeline as I do in my CSS:

```
<%= asset_path "img-11.jpg" %>
```

How does one rewrite the markup above to call `asset_path` within the context of a HAML template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HAML is basically the same, but without the surrounding brackets if you're doing it inline:

```
= asset_path "img-11.jpg"
```

Otherwise you should be able to use it in the definition:

```
%img{:alt => "image description", :src => asset_path("img-11.jpg")}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, use `= image_tag('img-11.jpg', alt: 'Image Description')`, but in the general case, use `= function_name_or_ruby_code` to evaluate any arbitrary Ruby and output the result.

You can use `- ruby_code` to evaluate Ruby *without* outputting the result.